# Data not loaded in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

i have used the following code to load the datatable using ajax. The data is not loaded in the database,

```
$('#new_table').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{
    "url": "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Members/membergetajax",
    "dataType": "json",
    "type": "POST",
    "dataSrc": "",
    },
    "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
    "pageLength": 5,
    "columnDefs": [{
        "className": "dt-center", "targets": 0
    },{
        "className": "dt-center", "targets": 1
    },{
        "className": "dt-center", "targets": 2
    }],
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id"},
        { "data": "first_name" },
        { "data": "member_id" }
    ]   
});
```

the data from ajax is in the format

```
 "data":[
     {"id":"1","first_name":"Arun","member_id":"Mem01"},
     {"id":"2","first_name":"Dinesh","member_id":"  Mem02 "},
     {"id":"3","first_name":"Ramesh  ","member_id":"Mem03 "},
     {"id":"4","first_name":"Mahesh ","member_id":"Mem04 "},
     {"id":"5","first_name":"Rajesh ","member_id":"Mem05"}
 ]
```

Please help me find the issue, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) you have two possibilities:

- set **dataSrc** to **data** -->"dataSrc": "data"
- your ajax call should return only **data** value:

  ```
  [{
     "id": "1",
     "first_name": "Arun",
      "member_id": "Mem01"
  }, {
     "id": "2",
     "first_name": "Dinesh",
     "member_id": "  Mem02 "
  }, {
      "id": "3",
      "first_name": "Ramesh  ",
      "member_id": "Mem03 "
  }, {
      "id": "4",
      "first_name": "Mahesh ",
      "member_id": "Mem04 "
  }, {
      "id": "5",
      "first_name": "Rajesh ",
      "member_id": "Mem05"
  }]
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding name property.

```
"columns": [
    { "data": "id", "name":"id"},
    { "data": "first_name", "name": "first_name" },
    { "data": "member_id" , "name": "member_id" }
]
```

if you are sending parameters uppercase try also like this: { "data": "id", "name":"Id"},